# How do you get permission to use a copyright before the copyright holder has obtained their certificate from the government?

Tags: united-states, copyright, contract-law, licensing, business

I'm in a musical, and I am helping the lyricist and composers to obtain their individual copyrights. The official certificate will not arrive for [around nine months](http://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-what.html#certificate).

I'm also recording and producing the show's soundtrack, and putting it up online for sale. It will be ready to go up for sale in about two months time.

How do I obtain permission from each of these copyright holders, before they have received their certificate from the government?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lyricist and composers already have copyright. Copyright exists for the moment of creation: registration is not necessary to enforce copyright rights and to grant licences. Registration in the US is merely useful if you want to prove that you own the copyright which otherwise would require providing evidence of the date of creation, priority etc. Most countries do not have copyright registers.

Similarly, you will have copyright in the derivative work of the soundtrack from the moment of its creation.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I obtain permission from each of these copyright holders, before they have received their certificate from the government?

You ask them, and potentially negotiate with them, until they agree to give you permission. Possession of a certificate is not a prerequisite for a copyright owner to grant permission to another to copy the protected work. As noted in Dale M's answer, the copyright itself does not depend on the certificate.  (Registration of copyright, in the US, affects the kind of damages you can claim in the event of infringement.)